# trying to create windows service from console application but it will not install

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

I am trying to use this tutorial from microsoft.... [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

I cannot get installutil to install it... I keep getting "Remove InstallState file because there are no installers."

There is clearly an installer in the exe.... here is the installer as it exists in my code:

```
        // Provide the ProjectInstaller class which allows 
    // the service to be installed by the Installutil.exe tool
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public class ProjectInstaller : Installer
    {
        private ServiceProcessInstaller process;
        private ServiceInstaller service;

        public ProjectInstaller()
        {
            process = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
            process.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
            service = new ServiceInstaller();
            service.ServiceName = "WCFWindowsServiceSample";
            Installers.Add(process);
            Installers.Add(service);
        }
    }
}
```

This is pretty annoying at this point.  If someone could look at the Microsoft article which is pretty simple I would appreciate any help.  With the installer there, I don't know why the installutil will not find it.

Yes I am running a visual studio command prompt as an administrator to do this.

Comment: Is there more information output, or just the "Remove InstallState..." message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oddly to fix this I needed to move the installer to a new cs file and that did it.  I simply created a new class file and moved the exact same class from the main file to this other file and it installed ok.  It doesn't make sense to me but this is a workaround for those who may be interested.

Comment: Maybe the project needed a rebuild. I have seen VS have bugs in that it does not always rebuild when necessary.